# Speed up the apply function in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a Dataframe containing date in string format. Dates look like this: 19620201 so with year first, then month, then day.

I want to convert those dates into Datetime. I tried to use this:
`pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

But it doesn't work because some date have the day to "00" sometimes it's the month and sometimes it's even the year.

I don't wanna drop those dates because I still wnat the years or month.

So i tried to write a function like this one:

```py
def handle_the_00_case(date):
    try:
        if date.endswith("0000"):
            return pd.to_datetime(date[:-4], format="%Y")
        elif date.endswith("00"):
            return pd.to_datetime(date[:-2], format="%Y%m")

        return pd.to_datetime(date, format="%Y%m%d")
    except ValueError:
        return
```

And use the following statement:
`df.Date.apply(handle_the_00_case)`

But this is really too long to compute.

Do you have an idea on how I can improve the speed of this ?
I tried the `np.vectorize()` and the swifter library but this doesn't work, I know I should change the way I wrote the function but i don't know how.

Thank you if you can help me ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first convert the column to valid dates, and then convert to datetime only once:

```
date = df['Date'].str.replace('0000$','0101')
date = date.str.replace('00$','01')
date = pd.to_datetime(date, format="%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: Yeah thank you ! I just tried, this is for now the fastest method I tried. It works really great !
Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ClementHuriaux - What is time in your data? It is faster like `np.where` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes it is if I take the initalisation time (I mean the assignement to d1, d2 etc.). The np.where is way faster to compute (4.9ms) but the overall time is 2.8s when I took the all time.

The solution of Daniel is longer to compute but at the end, the overall time is 1.6s, so it is just a bit faster

Answer (score 2):

First idea is use vectorized solution with pass column to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and generate ouput column by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[:-4], format="%Y", errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[:-2], format="%Y%m", errors='coerce')
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m%d", errors='coerce')

m1 = df['Date'].str.endswith("0000")
m2 = df['Date'].str.endswith("00")

df['Date_out'] = np.where(m1, d1, np.where(m2, d2, d3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works so nicely. Just tried on my  650000 rows. With the apply it took 67s. With the np.where, it took 4.9 ms.
I am going to read the docs about np.where to go further. Once again thank you very much ! :)